# How to get multiple or single values in text?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model for search.

```
public class Search{
  public string SearchId{ get; set;}
}
```

I am getting this in my asp.net mvc action fo controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(Search search){
...
...
}
```

When user set an ID value intext box, I am searching using entity framework.

But my clients want search multiple ids that comma seperated like following

```
  1,2,3,4,5
```

So I want to understand the SearchId value if multiple or single. So how can I understand? Using a pattern test or else?

Comment: `public ActionResult(Search search){` that's no valid syntax! You are missing a method name.

Comment: yes updated the method name

Comment: Could you please provide more details regarding SearchId? Is it a string that contains comma separated integers (eg. "1" or "1,2,3,4") or it can contain some other things?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your search to a string like, and split them into an array of ints:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string search)
{
    int[] ints = search.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    
    var results = from customer in context.Customers
            where ints.Contains(customer.Id)
            select customer;

    //todo: handle results
}
```

It should not make a difference if there is only one ID in the array.

Comment: Mind that this works only for a small number of "ints".

Comment: The question should be, why would you let your users search on ID's :-)

Comment: Agreed. That's also a valid question.

Comment: They are getting multiple ids via mail or excel tables from out sources. So they want to search by typing all id values ​​in text box instead of searching one by one.

Comment: @barteloma Ok. But mind that this will be converted to a "WHERE IN (...)" which has a maximum of items it can take (which is surprisingly low) and the more items, the worse it will perform. I am not saying "don't do it". Just check if you want to switch to a different apporach if id count > N. Maybe it doesn't even apply to you, because you get max ... idk 10 ids or so. But then I'd make sure to only allow a certain amount of ids max (don't trust user input).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(Search search){
    var numbers = search.SearchId.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
    
    //to understand the SearchId value if multiple or single
    if(numbers.Count == 1){
       // SearchId value is single
    }
    else if(numbers.Count > 1)
   //SearchId value has multiple value
}
```

Comment: OP: For a production-ready version, you'll probably also want to account for empty string (`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`) and parsing errors. Never trust user input.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to understand if SearchId value is multiple or single you can just split your SearchId by "," to array and check array length (But I wouldn't say that this is the best solution).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(Search search){
   var ids = search.SearchId.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   bool isMultiple = ids.Length > 1;

}
```

But if your SearchId contains only a comma separated string of integers, there is a better way. First of all you need to change the contract from

```
public ActionResult Search(Search search)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Search(int[] ids)
```

Because it streamlines the process and you don't need to split the SearchId  string into array of substrings and after that parse each element of array to integer. And in this case you should understand that you are trying to parse an input from user and there is a chance that you will get something in input string that you can't parse into integer (eg. "1,2,3,e,t") and you need either wrap int.Parse by try-catch block or use int.TryParse.
And another thing probably you always return and array as a search response you don't need to worry if a user passes single id or multiple ids because you always return an array and there is no difference if you return an array of one element or an array or multiple elements